# variable type checking

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list containing strings. These strings are either words or integer values. For example this list might look like this:

```
['0', 'Negate', '-3', '2', 'SPECIALCASE', '3']
```

Now, based on their type (integer or string), I want to treat them differently. However, as you have noticed I can't use `isinstace()`. I can still use `type()` and try to convert the integer values using the `int()` function and put the whole thing in a try-except method to avoid raising errors for the conversion of words. But this seems hackish to me. Do you know the right way of handling this case? Thanks in advance!

Comment: "try to convert the integer values using the int() function " - that's the way to go or you use a regular expression...

Comment: the best way to do this very much depends on what you want the final result to be, how do you want `'-3'` to be handled? should that be an `int`? what if you have `2.45` should that be a string or a number? should it be converted to a `float` or an `int`? probably your best shot should be try/except unless you want to go into bitwise checks.

Comment: You say you want to treat them differently based on type, but is that what you *really* want? Python isn't designed for type-checking, it's designed as a duck-typed language. Do what you want based on *if the object can do it* not *what type it is*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pythonic way of "Don't ask permission, ask for forgiveness":

```
lst = ['0', 'Negate', '-3', '2', 'SPECIALCASE', '3']

for item in lst:
    try:
        int_number = int(item)
    except ValueError:
        # handle the special case here
```

Note, that this should be done if you expect that only few items in the list are going to be the 'special' case items. Otherwise do the checks as @doomster advices.

Answer (score 3):

I'd take a different approach. If you know all possible "special" words, check for these. Everything else must be an int:

```
keywords = {'Negate', 'SPECIALCASE'}
tmp = []
for i in lis:
    if i in keywords:
        tmp.append(i)
    else
        tmp.append(int(i))
```

Of course, if you want to accept anything but ints without conversion, then trying to convert and falling back to unconverted use is the way to go.

Comment: +1, a good approach if possible (although if the keywords are very rare, it might be sub-optimal). The building of the list could, however, be simplified to a [list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw): `tmp = [i if i in keywords else int(i) for i in lis]`

Answer (score 0):

For reference, here's a regex approach. This may be overkill.

```
mylist = ['0', 'Negate', '-3', '2', 'SPECIALCASE', '3']

import re
p = re.compile(r'-?\d+')
[p.match(e) is not None for e in mylist]
# returns [True, False, True, True, False, True]
```

This returns a list with `True` for any strings that optionally start with a `-`, then contain one or more digits; `False` for any other strings.

Or if you don't need a list but just want to perform different operations:

```
for item in mylist:
    if p.match(item):
        # it's a number
    else:
        # it's a string
```

The above works becasue `None` (i.e. no match) evaluates to `False` and anything else (when it comes to regex matches) evaluates to `True`. If you want to be more explicit you can use `if p.match(item) is not None:`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use type conversion to check whether it's an integer or string,

```
def is_integer(input):
  try:
    int(input)
    return True
  except:
    return False

for item in ['0', 'Negate', '-3', '2', 'SPECIALCASE', '3']:
  if is_integer(item):
     ...
  else:
     ...
```

Comment: Don't use `except` without specifying the exception, it can hide bugs and make it extremely hard to find problems.